# mesos slave on different host unable to add itself

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Mesos slave is unable to add itself to the cluster. Right now i have 3 machine, with 3 slaves running and 1 master.

But at the mesos page i can see just one master and one slave (same as the master's host present). I can see the marathon running, app etc.. 
But just the other slaves are unable to connect to the master.

slave logs ::

```
I0825 21:30:00.971642  4110 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0825 21:30:01.000732  4106 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@127.0.1.1:5051) connected to ZooKeeper
I0825 21:30:01.000821  4106 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0825 21:30:01.000874  4106 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0825 21:30:01.007753  4106 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='9')
I0825 21:30:01.008038  4106 group.cpp:656] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000009' in ZooKeeper
W0825 21:30:01.020577  4106 detector.cpp:444] Leading master master@127.0.1.1:5050 is using a Protobuf binary format when registering with ZooKeeper (info): this will be deprecated as of Mesos 0.24 (see MESOS-2340)
I0825 21:30:01.021152  4106 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is detected
I0825 21:30:01.021353  4106 status_update_manager.cpp:176] Pausing sending status updates
I0825 21:30:01.021385  4105 slave.cpp:684] New master detected at master@127.0.1.1:5050
I0825 21:30:01.022073  4105 slave.cpp:709] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
E0825 21:30:01.022299  4113 socket.hpp:107] Shutdown failed on fd=11: Transport endpoint is not connected [107]
```

zookeeer on master ::

```
 ls /mesos
[info_0000000009, info_0000000010, log_replicas]
 ls /mesos/info_0000000009
[]
```

Please note the lines in slave logs :

```
Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000009' in ZooKeeper
```

and then why slave assumes the master as 127.0.1.1:5050 .. i never specified that

```
Leading master master@127.0.1.1:5050
```

but zookeeper returns 
      ls /mesos/info_0000000009
        []

looked into master's zookeeper and found that it was not set at all.. is t a bug in mesos or ki am missing some configuration..

also, the zookeeper logs on master closed the client connection(may now client started to connect to some other master)

```
2015-08-25 21:30:01,882 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxn@349] - caught 
end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x14f657dafeb000d, likely cl
ient has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-25 21:30:01,884 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed
 socket connection for client /192.168.0.3:53125 which had sessionid 0x14f657dafeb000d
2015-08-25 21:30:01,952 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - 
Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.3:53166
```

Note : slave on the same host as the master works perfectly fine.

TRYING TO RESOLVE IT OVER MORE THAN 2 DAYS NOW .. PLEASEE HELP..

Looks like a bug to me .. where can i see the current master in zookeeper .. is it something like  /mesos/info_0000000009  ? but  i was getting the in zookeeper

ls /mesos/info_0000000009
[]

an empty array thr .. is this correct because from client logs were trying to look for this : ...

```
I0825 21:30:01.008038  4106 group.cpp:656] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000009' in ZooKeeper
W0825 21:30:01.020577  4106 detector.cpp:444] Leading master master@127.0.1.1:5050 is using a Protobuf binary format when registering with ZooKeeper (info): this will be deprecated as of Mesos 0.24 (see MESOS-2340)
I0825 21:30:01.021152  4106 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is detected
```

and then client tries for 127.0.1.1:5050

## Here is the complete slave logs:

```
Log file created at: 2015/08/27 07:12:56
Running on machine: vvwslave1
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0827 07:12:56.406455  1303 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0827 07:12:56.438398  1303 main.cpp:162] Build: 2015-07-24 10:05:39 by root
I0827 07:12:56.438534  1303 main.cpp:164] Version: 0.23.0
I0827 07:12:56.438634  1303 main.cpp:167] Git tag: 0.23.0
I0827 07:12:56.438733  1303 main.cpp:171] Git SHA: 4ce5475346a0abb7ef4b7ffc9836c5836d7c7a66
I0827 07:12:56.510270  1303 containerizer.cpp:111] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem
I0827 07:12:56.566021  1329 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@127.0.1.1:5051) connected to ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:56.566082  1329 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0827 07:12:56.566108  1329 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:56.571959  1303 main.cpp:249] Starting Mesos slave
I0827 07:12:56.587656  1303 slave.cpp:190] Slave started on 1)@127.0.1.1:5051
I0827 07:12:56.587723  1303 slave.cpp:191] Flags at startup: --authenticatee="crammd5" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and
_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" -
-cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="mesos" --default_role="*" --disk_wa
tch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_sandbox_di
rectory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --enforce_container_
disk_quota="false" --executor_registration_timeout="1mins" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_
dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" 
--hadoop_home="" --help="false" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher_dir=
"/usr/libexec/mesos" --log_dir="/var/log/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --master="zk://192.168.0.2:2
281/mesos" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --port="505
1" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registrat
ion_backoff_factor="1secs" --resource_monitoring_interval="1secs" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --strict="true
" --switch_user="true" --version="false" --work_dir="/tmp/mesos"
I0827 07:12:56.592327  1303 slave.cpp:354] Slave resources: cpus(*):2; mem(*):979; disk(*):67653; ports(*):[31000-32
000]
I0827 07:12:56.592576  1303 slave.cpp:384] Slave hostname: vvwslave1
I0827 07:12:56.592608  1303 slave.cpp:389] Slave checkpoint: true
I0827 07:12:56.633998  1330 state.cpp:36] Recovering state from '/tmp/mesos/meta'
I0827 07:12:56.644068  1330 status_update_manager.cpp:202] Recovering status update manager
I0827 07:12:56.644907  1330 containerizer.cpp:316] Recovering containerizer
I0827 07:12:56.650073  1330 slave.cpp:4026] Finished recovery
I0827 07:12:56.650527  1330 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources
I0827 07:12:56.650653  1330 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0827 07:12:56.657416  1329 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='14')
I0827 07:12:56.657564  1329 group.cpp:656] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000014' in ZooKeeper
W0827 07:12:56.659080  1329 detector.cpp:444] Leading master master@127.0.1.1:5050 is using a Protobuf binary format
 when registering with ZooKeeper (info): this will be deprecated as of Mesos 0.24 (see MESOS-2340)
I0827 07:12:56.677889  1329 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is detected
I0827 07:12:56.677989  1329 slave.cpp:684] New master detected at master@127.0.1.1:5050
I0827 07:12:56.678146  1326 status_update_manager.cpp:176] Pausing sending status updates
I0827 07:12:56.678195  1329 slave.cpp:709] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0827 07:12:56.678239  1329 slave.cpp:720] Detecting new master
I0827 07:12:56.678591  1329 slave.cpp:3087] master@127.0.1.1:5050 exited
W0827 07:12:56.678702  1329 slave.cpp:3090] Master disconnected! Waiting for a new master to be elected
E0827 07:12:56.678460  1332 socket.hpp:107] Shutdown failed on fd=11: Transport endpoint is not connected [107]
E0827 07:12:57.068922  1332 socket.hpp:107] Shutdown failed on fd=11: Transport endpoint is not connected [107]
E0827 07:12:58.829129  1332 socket.hpp:107] Shutdown failed on fd=11: Transport endpoint is not connected [107]
```

## And the complete zookeeper logs running on master on master

```
2015-08-27 07:12:42,672 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@101] - Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cf
g
2015-08-27 07:12:42,718 - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerConfig@283] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (igno
ring)
2015-08-27 07:12:42,720 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 10
2015-08-27 07:12:42,720 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2015-08-27 07:12:42,721 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2015-08-27 07:12:42,721 - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running
  in standalone mode
2015-08-27 07:12:42,741 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@101] - Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cf
g
2015-08-27 07:12:42,765 - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerConfig@283] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (igno
ring)
2015-08-27 07:12:42,765 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@95] - Starting server
2015-08-27 07:12:42,776 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5--1, built on 06/
10/2013 17:26 GMT
2015-08-27 07:12:42,776 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=vvw
2015-08-27 07:12:42,776 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_79
2015-08-27 07:12:42,776 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-08-27 07:12:42,777 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
2015-08-27 07:12:42,777 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar
2015-08-27 07:12:42,777 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
2015-08-27 07:12:42,779 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-08-27 07:12:42,779 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-08-27 07:12:42,779 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2015-08-27 07:12:42,779 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-08-27 07:12:42,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=3.19.0-25-generic
2015-08-27 07:12:42,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=zookeeper
2015-08-27 07:12:42,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/var/lib/zookeeper
2015-08-27 07:12:42,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/
2015-08-27 07:12:42,789 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@726] - tickTime set to 2000
2015-08-27 07:12:42,789 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@735] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2015-08-27 07:12:42,789 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@744] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2015-08-27 07:12:42,806 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@94] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281
2015-08-27 07:12:42,826 - INFO  [main:FileSnap@83] - Reading snapshot /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.705
2015-08-27 07:12:42,859 - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@240] - Snapshotting: 0x728 to /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/snap
shot.728
2015-08-27 07:12:44,848 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted sock
et connection from /192.168.0.2:44500
2015-08-27 07:12:44,857 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request
 from old client /192.168.0.2:44500; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:44,859 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting 
to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44500
2015-08-27 07:12:44,862 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@199] - Creating new log file: log.729
2015-08-27 07:12:45,299 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10000 with nego
tiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44500
2015-08-27 07:12:45,505 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted sock
et connection from /192.168.0.2:44501
2015-08-27 07:12:45,506 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request
 from old client /192.168.0.2:44501; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:45,506 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting 
to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44501
2015-08-27 07:12:45,509 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted sock
et connection from /192.168.0.2:44502
2015-08-27 07:12:45,510 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request
 from old client /192.168.0.2:44502; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:45,510 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44502
2015-08-27 07:12:45,538 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.2:44503
2015-08-27 07:12:45,538 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.2:44504
2015-08-27 07:12:45,538 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request from old client /192.168.0.2:44503; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:45,539 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44503
2015-08-27 07:12:45,539 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request from old client /192.168.0.2:44504; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:45,539 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44504
2015-08-27 07:12:45,564 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10001 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44501
2015-08-27 07:12:45,674 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10002 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44502
2015-08-27 07:12:45,675 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10003 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44503
2015-08-27 07:12:45,676 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10004 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44504
2015-08-27 07:12:46,183 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.2:44506
2015-08-27 07:12:46,189 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44506
2015-08-27 07:12:46,232 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10005 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44506
2015-08-27 07:12:48,195 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.2:44508
2015-08-27 07:12:48,196 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44508
2015-08-27 07:12:48,212 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10006 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.0.2:44508
2015-08-27 07:12:49,872 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.2:44509
2015-08-27 07:12:49,873 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request from old client /192.168.0.2:44509; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:49,873 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.2:44509
2015-08-27 07:12:49,878 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10007 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.2:44509
2015-08-27 07:12:56,161 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.3:60436
2015-08-27 07:12:56,161 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@793] - Connection request from old client /192.168.0.3:60436; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2015-08-27 07:12:56,161 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2281:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.0.3:60436
2015-08-27 07:12:56,189 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@595] - Established session 0x14f6cd241e10008 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /192.168.0.3:60436
```

## And the logs from master node

```
I0827 07:12:45.412888  1604 leveldb.cpp:176] Opened db in 567.381081ms
I0827 07:12:45.469497  1604 leveldb.cpp:183] Compacted db in 56.508537ms
I0827 07:12:45.469674  1604 leveldb.cpp:198] Created db iterator in 21452ns
I0827 07:12:45.502590  1604 leveldb.cpp:204] Seeked to beginning of db in 32.834339ms
I0827 07:12:45.502900  1604 leveldb.cpp:273] Iterated through 3 keys in the db in 101809ns
I0827 07:12:45.503026  1604 replica.cpp:744] Replica recovered with log positions 73 -> 74 with 0 holes and 0 unlear
ned
I0827 07:12:45.507745  1643 log.cpp:238] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
I0827 07:12:45.507983  1643 recover.cpp:449] Starting replica recovery
I0827 07:12:45.508095  1643 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in VOTING status
I0827 07:12:45.508167  1643 recover.cpp:464] Recover process terminated
I0827 07:12:45.536058  1604 main.cpp:383] Starting Mesos master
I0827 07:12:45.559154  1604 master.cpp:368] Master 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604 (vvwmaster) started on 127.0.1
.1:5050
I0827 07:12:45.559239  1604 master.cpp:370] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="Hierarchica
lDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --framework_sorter="drf" --hel
p="false" --hostname="vvwmaster" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --log_auto_initialize="true" --log_dir="/var/log
/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --quorum
="1" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_s
tore_timeout="5secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_rereg
ister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="/var/l
ib/mesos" --zk="zk://192.168.0.2:2281/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I0827 07:12:45.559460  1604 master.cpp:417] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I0827 07:12:45.559491  1604 master.cpp:422] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I0827 07:12:45.559587  1604 master.cpp:459] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W0827 07:12:45.559619  1604 authenticator.cpp:504] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused.
I0827 07:12:45.559909  1604 authenticator.cpp:511] Initializing server SASL
I0827 07:12:45.564357  1642 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.564539  1642 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0827 07:12:45.564590  1642 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.675650  1644 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(2)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.675717  1644 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I0827 07:12:45.675750  1644 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.676774  1639 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(3)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.676828  1639 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0827 07:12:45.676857  1639 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.678182  1640 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(4)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.678235  1640 group.cpp:787] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0827 07:12:45.678380  1640 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.809567  1645 network.hpp:415] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I0827 07:12:45.816505  1644 group.cpp:656] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000013' in ZooKeeper
I0827 07:12:45.820705  1645 network.hpp:463] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@127.0.1.1:5050 }
I0827 07:12:46.020447  1644 contender.cpp:131] Joining the ZK group
I0827 07:12:46.020498  1639 master.cpp:1420] Successfully attached file '/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO'
I0827 07:12:46.078451  1643 contender.cpp:247] New candidate (id='14') has entered the contest for leadership
I0827 07:12:46.078984  1645 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='14')
I0827 07:12:46.079110  1645 group.cpp:656] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000014' in ZooKeeper
W0827 07:12:46.084359  1645 detector.cpp:444] Leading master master@127.0.1.1:5050 is using a Protobuf binary format when registering with ZooKeeper (info): this will be deprecated as of Mesos 0.24 (see MESOS-2340)
I0827 07:12:46.084485  1645 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is detected
I0827 07:12:46.084553  1645 master.cpp:1481] The newly elected leader is master@127.0.1.1:5050 with id 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604
I0827 07:12:46.084653  1645 master.cpp:1494] Elected as the leading master!
I0827 07:12:46.084682  1645 master.cpp:1264] Recovering from registrar
I0827 07:12:46.084812  1645 registrar.cpp:313] Recovering registrar
I0827 07:12:46.085160  1645 log.cpp:661] Attempting to start the writer
I0827 07:12:46.085683  1639 replica.cpp:477] Replica received implicit promise request with proposal 18
I0827 07:12:46.231271  1639 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 145.505945ms
I0827 07:12:46.231402  1639 replica.cpp:345] Persisted promised to 18
I0827 07:12:46.231667  1640 coordinator.cpp:230] Coordinator attemping to fill missing position
I0827 07:12:46.231801  1640 log.cpp:677] Writer started with ending position 74
I0827 07:12:46.232197  1646 leveldb.cpp:438] Reading position from leveldb took 60443ns
I0827 07:12:46.232319  1646 leveldb.cpp:438] Reading position from leveldb took 21312ns
I0827 07:12:46.232934  1646 registrar.cpp:346] Successfully fetched the registry (247B) in 148.019968ms
I0827 07:12:46.233131  1646 registrar.cpp:445] Applied 1 operations in 17888ns; attempting to update the 'registry'
I0827 07:12:46.234346  1640 log.cpp:685] Attempting to append 286 bytes to the log
I0827 07:12:46.234463  1640 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND action at position 75
I0827 07:12:46.234748  1645 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 75
I0827 07:12:46.274888  1645 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (305 bytes) to leveldb took 40.044935ms
I0827 07:12:46.275140  1645 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 75
I0827 07:12:46.275503  1646 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 75
I0827 07:12:46.307917  1646 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (307 bytes) to leveldb took 32.320539ms
I0827 07:12:46.308076  1646 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 75
I0827 07:12:46.308112  1646 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned APPEND action at position 75
I0827 07:12:46.308668  1646 registrar.cpp:490] Successfully updated the 'registry' in 75.472128ms
I0827 07:12:46.308749  1646 registrar.cpp:376] Successfully recovered registrar
I0827 07:12:46.308888  1646 log.cpp:704] Attempting to truncate the log to 75
I0827 07:12:46.309002  1646 master.cpp:1291] Recovered 1 slaves from the Registry (247B) ; allowing 10mins for slaves to re-register
I0827 07:12:46.309056  1646 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE action at position 76
I0827 07:12:46.309252  1646 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 76
I0827 07:12:46.352067  1646 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (16 bytes) to leveldb took 42.749912ms
I0827 07:12:46.352377  1646 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 76
I0827 07:12:46.352900  1646 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 76
I0827 07:12:46.407814  1646 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 54.686166ms
I0827 07:12:46.408033  1646 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 50800ns
I0827 07:12:46.408068  1646 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 76
I0827 07:12:46.408102  1646 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 76
I0827 07:12:46.884490  1644 master.cpp:3332] Registering slave at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (vvw) with id 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604-S0
I0827 07:12:46.900085  1644 registrar.cpp:445] Applied 1 operations in 43323ns; attempting to update the 'registry'
I0827 07:12:46.901564  1639 log.cpp:685] Attempting to append 440 bytes to the log
I0827 07:12:46.901736  1639 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND action at position 77
I0827 07:12:46.902035  1639 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 77
I0827 07:12:46.947882  1639 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (459 bytes) to leveldb took 45.777578ms
I0827 07:12:46.948067  1639 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 77
I0827 07:12:46.948422  1639 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 77
I0827 07:12:46.992007  1639 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (461 bytes) to leveldb took 43.518061ms
I0827 07:12:46.992187  1639 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 77
I0827 07:12:46.992249  1639 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned APPEND action at position 77
I0827 07:12:46.992826  1640 registrar.cpp:490] Successfully updated the 'registry' in 92.466176ms
I0827 07:12:46.992949  1639 log.cpp:704] Attempting to truncate the log to 77
I0827 07:12:46.993027  1639 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE action at position 78
I0827 07:12:46.993371  1639 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 78
I0827 07:12:46.993588  1640 master.cpp:3395] Registered slave 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604-S0 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (vvw) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):1846; disk(*):141854; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0827 07:12:46.993785  1644 hierarchical.hpp:528] Added slave 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604-S0 (vvw) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):1846; disk(*):141854; ports(*):[31000-32000] (allocated: )
I0827 07:12:47.018685  1641 master.cpp:3687] Received update of slave 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604-S0 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (vvw) with total oversubscribed resources 
I0827 07:12:47.018934  1641 hierarchical.hpp:588] Slave 20150827-071245-16842879-5050-1604-S0 (vvw) updated with oversubscribed resources  (total: cpus(*):4; mem(*):1846; disk(*):141854; ports(*):[31000-32000], allocated: )
I0827 07:12:47.036170  1639 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (16 bytes) to leveldb took 42.72315ms
I0827 07:12:47.036388  1639 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 78
```

Comment: How do you start your slaves and master(s)?

Comment: sudo service mesos-master retstart . and sudo service mesos-slave restart..

Comment: Could you please provide complete logs?

Comment: Hi rukletsov, i added the complete slave logs and zookeeper logs..

Comment: also added master logs .. reached 30k chars in stackoverflow

Comment: check these logs in master ..  (group(1)@127.0.1.1:5050) .. is these causing up issues

Comment: Hi rukletsov, any idea whats wrong

Comment: It's a bit hard to say, because it looks like you provided logs from different runs (the Master logs ends at 07:12:47 while the slave logs starts at 07:12:56), also instead of a clean registration, your slave reregisters, which signals of previous runs. Could you please do a clean run and post logs (you can create gists and post links here).

Do you have any firewall rules on that machine?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-3tMS-2K0QenBEN25VYkkzOTA/view?usp=sharing : please check the logs..

Comment: did not installed mesos-dns, hope that should not be the problem

Answer (score 6):

> "But at the mesos page i can see just one master and one slave (same as the master's host present)."

Most probably this happens because the master is not able to establish connection to agents (aka slaves) living on other machines. Right now (this may change with the new HTTP API), the master must be able to open a connection to an agent, which means an agent must report a non-local IP when to registers with the master. From your logs it looks like agents bind to local IPs (`127.0.1.1)`. You can change that via `--ip` flag.

Comment: why should slaves talk to master directly.. why not use zookeeper via /etc/mesos/zk

Comment: there is bug .. the mesos slaves doesn't use zookeeper config at /etc/mesros/zk to find the master ..  i am using  tutorials in mesosphere.com  to install

Comment: The mesos nodes have to be able to initiate a connection to each other (master->slave, slave->master)  and that can only be done if the IP-address the node is reporting actually is public. Your logs show that 127.0.1.1 is used that that most likely is not a public address  -> rukletsov's answer is spot on - you may want to consider reading it again :)

Comment: Had the same problem, using the `--ip` flag (to the public ip) on the slave definitely fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are running mesos as a service, and I think there must be a configuration file where you should specify your master ip(or zookeeper ip) and the default value in the file is 127.0.1.1, so only your slave on the same machine with your master can connect to it. Because when running mesos-slave you must give it the master ip.

Comment: maybe in directory /etc/mesos-slave or /etc/mesos or something like that